# add Items (FILES) from Directory to Spinner List

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, spinner

i´m trying to add files from a directory to spinner list, but i got nothing, (spinner list is empty) hoyever the folder countains 3 files in it.

i checked whether the folder exists or not, (the folder exists)

then i tried to show a message telling if any file found in the folder (i got no message)

this is what i tried so far :

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    Button btnGetFiles;
    Spinner spinnerGetFiles;
    List<string> fileList;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        spinnerGetFiles = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinnerGetFiles);
        btnGetFiles = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnGetFiles);

        btnGetFiles.Click += delegate 
        {
            fileList = GetFilesFromDirectory("/storage/emulated/0/MyFolder");
            ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, fileList);
            spinnerGetFiles.Adapter = adapter;
        };
    }

    List<string> GetFilesFromDirectory(string strDirectoryPath)
    {            
        List<string> files = new List<string>();
        if (Directory.Exists(strDirectoryPath))
        {
            Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "Directory found", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            string[] fileList2 = Directory.GetFiles(strDirectoryPath);
            foreach (string file in fileList2)
            {
                files.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
                Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "File found : " + file, ToastLength.Long).Show();                   
            }
        }
        else { Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "No directory was found!!", ToastLength.Long).Show(); }
        return files;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you speaking about a spinner? The spinner is irrelevant. If you try to list a directory then nothing is listed. That is your problem.

Comment: If those three files are not created by your app then it is quite normal that your app cannot list them.

Comment: do you have permission to access that folder?

Comment: Hi, blackapps , step by step, when the app start (could) find the files, i want to add them to a The Spinner,

Comment: Hi Jason , yes the app have the permissions to Write and Read External storage

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

From the storage you accessed(`/storage/emulated/0/`),we could find that you want to access the `external storage`.

To access the external storage, we need to add the external storage permissions as follows:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And we also need to add [runtime permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/permissions?tabs=windows) after Android 6.0 (API level 23).

And there is an official sample here about how to access `external storage`, you can check it here: [local files](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/main/LocalFiles).

For more information, you can check: [External storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=windows).

And as a test, I added a Button to the sample code to get the generated file `count.txt` [local files](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/main/LocalFiles) using the following code, and it could list the file correctly:

```
    List<string> GetFilesFromDirectory(string strDirectoryPath)
    {
        List<string> files = new List<string>();


        string  dir = GetExternalFilesDir(null).AbsolutePath;   

        if (Directory.Exists(dir))
        {
            Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "Directory found", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            string[] fileList2 = Directory.GetFiles(dir);

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("the number of files is: " + fileList2.Count());

            foreach (string file in fileList2)
            {
                files.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
                Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "File found : " + file, ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
        }
        else { Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "No directory was found!!", ToastLength.Long).Show(); }
        return files;
    }
```

Comment: GetExternalFilesDir() gives an app private path for which you do not need any permission. It has nothing to do with /storage/emulated/0/MyFolder. Look at absolute path.

Comment: thank you, Jessie Zhang -MSFT , the below code show no message . System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("the number of files is: " + fileList2.Count());

Comment: Hi  @AnthonyMagerera,  you can double-check that the file actually exists in the folder you used.